# Menu bar HTML/CSS bad showing

Tags: html, css, menu, css-position

I want to create a menu bar with a list, but it's all in one place!
If I play with the position of the menu (absolute, fixed, ...), it's good, but I want that the menu will be fixed.

**CSS:**

```css
img.logo {
  max-height: 90px;
  width: auto;
  position: fixed;
  clip: rect(5px, 95px, 90px, 5px);
}

a,
li {
  color: inherit;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10%px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Odin rounded;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

***HTML:***
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">

<head>
  <title>Team NoMaD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="barre">
    <li>
      <a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="problem"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="main.html">Menu</a>
      <li><a href="members.html">Membres</a>
        <li><a href="calender.html">Calendrier</a>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**Run it and you will see what I see...**

**What is wrong?**
PS: Can you say how can I make it all in one line, like a real menu bar

Comment: remove position fixed from your li,a and reduce your left and right padding (or make them px instead of %)

Comment: Check `padding-right` value in `a, li` **10%px**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes by simplifying your css content.

You just need to use `display: block` and `float:left` to arrange your menu items properly. I've added a few more tweaks to it to suit what you wanted to achieve.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
 <title>Team NoMaD</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="barre">
  <li><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="problem"></a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html">Menu</a>
  <li><a href="members.html">Membres</a>
  <li><a href="calender.html">Calendrier</a>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `position:fixed` from `img-logo`, `a, li` and add `position:fixed` or `position:sticky` to their parent container

```css
.navbar{
  float: right;
  position: sticky /* use can use position:fixed */
}

 img.logo{
 max-height:90px;
 width:auto;
 clip: rect(5px,95px,90px,5px);
}
a, li{
 color:inherit;
 list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-left:5px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 font-size:16px;
 font-family:Odin rounded;
 vertical-align:text-top;
 text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
}
li    {
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
 <title>Team NoMaD</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
 <ul class="barre">
  <li><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="problem"></a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html">Menu</a>
  <li><a href="members.html">Membres</a>
  <li><a href="calender.html">Calendrier</a>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And can you say me how can I put all in one line, like normal menu bar (like stackoverflow menu bar on the top)

Comment: You mean vertical line??

Comment: stack overflow has two menu vertical on the left and horizontal one the to right

Comment: I mean on the top, where is the search bar

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
<head>
 <title>Team NoMaD</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  img.logo   {
 max-height:90px;
 width:auto;
 position:fixed;
 clip: rect(5px,95px,90px,5px);
}
a, li  {
 
    list-style: none;
    color: inherit;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Odin rounded;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline; 
}
li    {
 border:1px solid black;
}

***HTML:***
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="barre">
  <li><a href="main.html"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="problem"></a></li>
  <li><a href="main.html">Menu</a>
  <li><a href="members.html">Membres</a>
  <li><a href="calender.html">Calendrier</a>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Just changing display:inline-block to inline worked for me. Preview this on full page as this is not responsive example.
Hope This could help. :)